# Draggable divs not working if created by Ajax

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, draggable

I'm using jQuery and Ajax to load a bunch of divs into a scrollable div ("letterHolder"):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
$.ajax({
  url: "myphpscript.php",
  dataType: "json",   
  success: function(result) {
    $(".letterHolder").html(result['letter_array']);
  }
});
</script>
</head>

<body>

<div class="letterHolder">
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

The PHP script retrieves a list of filenames from the database and loads them into letterHolder, so it ends up looking like this:

```
<div class="letterHolder">
  <div class="drag_letter">file1</div>
  <div class="drag_letter">file2</div>
  <div class="drag_letter">file3</div>
  etc.
</div>
```

Now, I want to make those filename divs draggable, but this is not working:

```
$(".drag_letter").draggable({
 cursor: 'move',
 revert: true,
 helper: 'clone'   
});
```

It doesn't work if I put the draggable code into the page header, nor does it work if I put the code at the end of the page.

This was working fine before I tried creating the divs using Ajax.

Comment: If the content is added with ajax, you need to attach an event handler to that function. Use `.on()` to Attach an event handler

Comment: are you using `Jquery Ui` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Using jQuery or java script `append()` function for adding DOM into an element instead of html()
2. add `draggable` after appending elements

you should send file names Like `file1`... `file2`... as a Json array From server

and rewrite this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$.ajax({
    url: "myphpscript.php",
    dataType: "json",
    success: function(result) {
        $.each(result,function(k,v){
            $(".letterHolder").append($('<div></div>').html(v).addClass('drag_letter').draggable({
                cursor: 'move',
                revert: true,
                helper: 'clone'
            }));
        });
    }
});
</script>
```

Comment: This works, thank you! But I don't really understand what the "k" in this line means: $.each(result,function(k,v){.  Could you explain?

Comment: `$.each` is for fetching array `k` is array key and `v` is array value , that you can use `$(this)`  instead of `v` ;)  So Accept my Answer...

Answer (score 2):

I assume the reason this was working before you were using AJAX, but is not working with AJAX, is because you are calling `draggable()` with a selector for elements which are not yet in the DOM. If you call `draggable()` on the elements after receiving the AJAX result and appending the elements to the DOM it should work.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/15778930)

Comment: @CrisDeBlonde Although the wording is a bit aggresive, he in fact proposes a solution that does apply and answer the question

Comment: @CrisDeBlonde Sorry, I've edited to give a proper explanation.